# XUL set toolbarbutton width

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

how can i set the width for a toolbar button?
I've set it in the XUL and trying with the js but none of theses methods works using the

```
document.....setAttribute("style","width:50px")
```

How can i do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having something like this:

```
<toolbarpalette id="BrowserToolbarPalette">
   <toolbarbutton id="toolbarbuttonID"
      image='chrome://yourExt/content/images/logo.png'
      class="toolbarbutton-1 chromeclass-toolbar-additional"
   </toolbarbutton>
</toolbarpalette>
```

You can set the image size inside your css file:

```
#toolbarbuttonID .toolbarbutton-icon {
   width: 50px
   height:16px
}
```

If you want, you can also add an image of the height and width desired and add it as the button's image. It will stretch the size of the button:

Comment: @FilipeSilva did you know why a button with a firefox in windows has a different behaviour with a div margin position as in linux?